# Implementing an asynchronous delay in C++/CX

Tags: time, callback, interop, native, c++-cx

I am trying to write a function which, given a number of seconds and a callback, runs the callback after the given number of seconds. The callback does not have to be on the same thread. The target language is C++/CX.

I tried using Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPoolTimer, but the result is a memory access exception. The issue appears to be that the callback implementation (in native C++) can't be accessed from the managed thread that the timer is running its callback on.

```
ref class TimerDoneCallback {
private:
    function<void(void)> m_callback;
public:
    void EventCallback(ThreadPoolTimer^ timer) {
        m_callback(); // <-- memory exception here
    }
    TimerDoneCallback(function<void(void)> callback) : m_callback(callback) {}
};
void RealTimeDelayCall(const TimeSpan& duration, function<void(void)> callback) {
    auto t = ref new TimerDoneCallback(callback);
    auto e = ref new TimerElapsedHandler(t, &TimerDoneCallback::EventCallback);
    ThreadPoolTimer::CreateTimer(e, duration);
}
void Test() {
    RealTimeDelayCall(duration, [](){}); //after a delay, run 'do nothing'
}
```

I don't want to create a thread and sleep on it, because there may be many concurrent delays.

Comment: Awesome lambda expression, too bad `<>` doesn't fit :)  I'd guess at *this* being bogus, can't see what keeps the object alive.

Comment: The TimerDoneCallback instance should be kept alive by the fact that it is a ref class referenced by a timer callback. The anonymous function shouldn't need to be kept alive because it has no state.

Comment: Well, it does, the state is *this*.  The lambda captures it so it can call the instance method.  Well hidden isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. The initial callback that works, the timer callback, captures the 'TimerDoneCallback' instance. But the second callback, [](){}, has no 'this' to capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TimerDoneCallback instance is not kept alive - delegates in C++/CX take weak references to the target object (to avoid circular references).  You can override this behavior by using the extended overload of the delegate constructor:

```
auto e = ref new TimerElapsedHandler(t, &TimerDoneCallback::EventCallback, CallbackContext::Any, true);
```

The final bool parameter should be true for strong references, and false for weak references.  (False is the default.)

You could also consider using the timer class in PPL agents to make a delayed callback: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873170(v=vs.110).aspx to avoid needing to use ThreadPoolTimer.

Comment: This would explain the inconsistent behavior I was seeing based on seemingly unimportant code changes (i.e. I was accessing free'd memory so unrelated changes caused differences).

Comment: Whenever I try to create an event handler in the way you specified, I get a compiler error. "expected either '(<function-address>)' or '(<object-handle>, <member-address>)'"... Where did you source that line from?

Comment: Sorry - it's possible the compiler you are using does not contain these extra overloads (though in such a case I think you should always be getting strong references).  Is this a build compiler error or a intellisense compiler error (red squiggle)?  I believe with some prerelease versions these expanded delegate ctors will squiggle in the intellisense compiler but compile successfully with the build compiler.  (This is a bug which should be fixed in the final release.)